# Does every knot have a diagram such that every arc is a bridge?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Since the number of crossings in a knot diagram is the same as the number of arcs (or edges), can you construct a diagram of a knot where each arc crosses over exactly one other arc? My first thought would be to prove or disprove this with Reidermeister moves, but I couldn’t seem to find a way to make an argument because the 2nd and 3rd moves make things much more complicated.

Is there a way to prove or disprove this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_knot

Comment: As @NoahSchweber points out, the knot will have an alternating diagram if it does what you are suggesting.  There are non-alternating knots, so this is not true if you are looking at reduced diagrams.  So you will need to focus on a reduced non-alternating tangle and increasing the number of crossings to make it alternating.  I am not sure this is possible, but every questions about knots in respect to their diagrams seems to be possible.  Look at Tait's work on flyping?